# Using Firebase and FileProvider with Build Variants

Tags: android, firebase, android-fileprovider

I am  using build variants with Firebase and my application also needs to use FileProvider for sharing app files to be opened in 3rd party apps.
But when I am trying to send the URI in the intent, the app crashes giving following error.

`error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.debug/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170919_113955_102027655.jpg`

Heres my configuration

`String authority = getString(R.string.authority_provider);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, file);`

- Added file provider into AndroidManifest.xml at inside of application tag:

  `<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="@string/authority_provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
  </provider>`
- `file_paths.xml`

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths>
       <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/${applicationId}/files/Pictures" />
       <external-file-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/${applicationId}/files/Pictures" />
   </paths>`

As `Firebase` mandates using 2 application IDs to keep crash logs, analytics separate in Firebase Console

- String: authority_provider - added into build.gradle(app):

  `buildTypes {
     release {
         ---
         applicationIdSuffix "com.example"
         resValue "string", "authority_provider", "\"com.example.fileprovider\""
         ---
     }
     debug {
         ---
         applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
         resValue "string", "authority_provider", "\"com.example.debug.fileprovider\""
         ---
     }
  }`
- File: and creating file into ExternalFilesDir and saving downloaded data into it and using same file object to get URI.

  `File storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
  File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, fileExtension, storageDir);`

I have tryed following solution to solve but not worked for me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42555624/8240915
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42516202/8240915
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40463201/8240915
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989153/8240915

Also followed this blog post.

- https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/share-files-using-fileprovider

Comment: `name="my_images"`. You have that twice. For different paths. Not good. Use different names and use path="." for both.

Comment: Thank you its working. But found better and more safe solution. Just need to replace code of **file_paths.xml** with following: **`<paths> <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" /> </paths>`**